# 2 div floated but same height

Tags: html, css

Here's my html

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="box">
        <div class="float">
            <img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2f/db/miami-beach.jpg' />
        </div>
        <div class="float float_txt">
            text here!
        <p class"a_p">a</p>
        <p class"b_p">b</p>
        <p class"c_p">c</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.container{width:400px}
.box{display:inline-block}
.float{width:50%; float:left}
.float img{width: 100%; height:auto;}
.float_txt{background:red}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MdtR8/1/

`.container` has a dynamic width (responsive design) and image will auto-resize itself.

I need to have `.float_txt` at same height as image, but I need a REAL height because I must divide a b c in percentage. Example:

```
.a_p, .b_p{height: 20%}
.c_p{height:60%}
```

How I can to this? only css no js :S

Comment: What do you mean by _REAL height_?

Comment: @matewka I think they mean an integer.

Comment: could you not use offsetHeight?

Comment: You say ".container has a dynamic width" but you are hardcoding it to 400px? It's difficult to understand what you're asking, perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: .container have 400px in demo but in code have a parecentage like 30%. with real height I mean that browser can read a value in px and I can divide the div inside in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you solve it with `JQuery`. Here is the example of JQuery to calculate the height of `.float img` and add it to `float_txt` height.

```
$(".float_txt").css({
    'height': $('.float img').height()
});
```

It's just one solution using JQuery. It's absolutely easier than using only css.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdtR8/22/)

Comment: This won't work for responsive layouts, and the OP clearly stated that they don't want to use javascript, much less jQuery (even though it may be amazing and does all things).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the approaches.

I don't consider it to be **the** answer neither an elegant solution but this is one of the workarounds which actually meets the most important condition - it works (with some restrictions).

### **[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdtR8/28/)**

**First**, we must assume that everything inside the `.float_txt` will be wrapped within those three paragraphs - they're meant to be *20%*, *20%* and *60%* which is *100%* all together so there's no more space for any other elements. **Next**, we wrap all three paragraphs with a div and put a copy of the image next to this div. We'll add the `id="speculate"` to the image.
The whole HTML will look like that:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="box">
        <div class="float">
            <img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2f/db/miami-beach.jpg' />
        </div><div class="float float_txt">
            <img id='speculate' src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2f/db/miami-beach.jpg' />
            <div class='content'>
                <p class="a-p">a</p>
                <p class="b-p">b</p>
                <p class="c-p">c</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

We'll use the `#speculate` image to set the height of the `.float_txt` div. The image will have `visibility: hidden` which makes it invisible but still *occupying*_ the space in its container. The `.content` div will be positioned absolutely and spread to the whole space of the `.float_txt` with `top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0`.
The paragraphs will be also positoned absolutely and placed with the `top` property. The disadvantage here is the fact that we must know the percentage heights of the preceding paragraphs, e.g. to position the second paragraph we must set `top: 20%` because the first paragraph has `height: 20%`. I hope it's clear.

The whole CSS will look like this:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
}
.float {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
}
.float img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.float_txt {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

#speculate {
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.content p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.content .static {
    position: static;
}
.a-p {
    height: calc(20% + 20px);
    top: 20px;
}
.b-p {
    height: 20%;
    top: calc(20% + 20px);
}
.c-p {
    height: 60%;
    top: calc(40% + 20px);
}
```